# Two container next to each other at full width (each container can be hidden)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I searched a lot, but now  want to ask because I found no answer:

If have two div elements that should be located next to each other with full width (each exactly 50% of the full width). It could be that the first or the second div is hidden (style="display=none"). In this case the other div should be displayed in full width.

My solution is this:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px;">
            <div id="div1">
                ...
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0px;">
            <div id="div2">
               ...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That works almost perfect, BUT when both divs are displayed the first one seems to be 55% and the second one 45% of the width.

If course I can set the width of the div when hiding the other to 100%, but I want to avoid doing that.

Does anyone have a solution to make them both 50% when both are displayed.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine...

Comment: actually yes, but it depends on the content of the div. the first div has a bigger width than the second, so it is shown with about 55% and the second with 45%...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys,

thanks for your help. now i found what i was searching for:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td id="td1" style="padding: 0px; min-width:50%;">
            <div>
                ...                       
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="td2" style="padding: 0px; min-width:50%;">
            <div>
                ...                       
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

both td tags are next to each other and both take exactly 50%. when hiding td1 or td2, the other td goes into full width automatically.

best regards...

Answer (score 0):

**A JQuery approach with no tables**

You can achieve this with JQuery (or plain javascript) which I am assuming you are using to show/hide the elements anyway.

```
$("#ButtonOne").click(function () {
    $(".one").toggle();
    if($(".one").is(":visible")){
        $(".two").css("width", "50%");
    }
    else{
        $(".two").css("width", "100%");
    }
});
$("#ButtonTwo").click(function () {
    $(".two").toggle();
    if($(".two").is(":visible")){
        $(".one").css("width", "50%");
    }
    else{
        $(".one").css("width", "100%");
    }
});
```

The above JQuery assumes two buttons for toggling the visibility of the elements.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/RKR88/1/)

With the example, it should be noted that using 50% width with `inline-block` requires zero whitespace in between the elements. Hence the `</div><div...` requirement.

You will need some `vertical-align:top;` aswell to ensure the DIV elements stay in line.

---

Incase the link ever breaks, here is the accompanying HTML...

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="one">this is one</div><div class="two">this is two</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="ButtonOne" value="Toggle one" />
<input type="button" id="ButtonTwo" value="Toggle two" />
```

...and CSS...

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.one {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.two {
    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that solution. as i have mentioned i want to avoid to change css like the width with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout:fixed`:

EDIT:

You have to set the display:none on the td, not on the div.

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px; width:50%">
            <div id="div1" style="border: 1px solid black">
                This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text 
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0px; width:50%; display: none;">
            <div id="div2" style="border: 1px solid black">
               This isn't as long as the other text.
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've tested it on Chrome, Firefox and IE10

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but if one div is made invisible with style="display:none;" the other div should appear over the whole width...

Answer (score 0):

Can you place both divs in the same table cell?

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="div1">
                ...
            </div>
            <div id="div2">
               ...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could simply toggle a class....

```
table { width: 100%; padding:0; }
td { padding:0; margin:0; }
td > div { width: 50%; display: block; float: left; height: 50px; cursor: pointer; }
#div1 {background: #a00;}
#div2 {background: #00a;}
.wide {width: 100%;}
.hide { display: none;}
```

and the jquery...

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('wide');
    $('div').not(this).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/9VeP3/1/)

Would work for multiple divs easily: [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/9VeP3/3/)

Comment: thanks for that solution. as i have mentioned i want to avoid to change css like the width with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting width in the td itself, and when you want to hide any one div just add "display:none;" in the specified td instead of the div, then the remaining div will have 100% width.

```
 <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0px; width:50%;">
                <div id="div1" >
                    hii
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 0px;width:50%;">
                <div id="div2" style="">
                   byyee
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```